# How to convert byte string to byte array

Tags: c#

I already have bytes needed stocked in a string but i don't know how to re convert it into byte.

```
    public static void sender(string message)
    {
        string path = "path of file here";
        byte[] pictureArray = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        receiver("" + pictureArray);
    }

    public static void receiver(string message)
    {
        byte[] bytesReceived = message.ToByteArray(); //How i do this without convert my bytes into another bytes
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string

Comment: `"" + pictureArray` is not what you may think - as it's just "System.Byte[]" string https://dotnetfiddle.net/jYNWxP

Comment: What is a byte string?

Comment: As it is, your question in the context of the code sample makes hardly any sense. While obviously changing `string` to `byte[]` 'works', it is unclear what _actual_ problem are  you trying to solve (see [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=net-6.0) class, but you need to be sure which encoding you will be using.. *(UTF8, Unicode etc)*

```
public static void receiver(string message)
{
    byte[] bytesReceived = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message);
}
```

and vice versa:

```
public static void sender(byte[] data)
{
    string stringReceived = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
}
```

As I read, [`Encoding.Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=net-6.0#the-default-property-on-net-core) return UTF-8.

Comment: You're allowed to fix typo's ;-) but thanks

Comment: there is utf9... [RFC 4042](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4042) :D (look at the date)

Comment: It was April Fools joke